# Is the top entry and exit page in Webalizer reports the most popular page on my site?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers

According to Webalizer, the top entry and exit page to my website is "/blog/". This is where my Wordpress blog is situated. (There are static non-Wordpress pages on my site as well.)

Does that mean this is the most popular page on my site?

I think most of the visits to the blog are made by bots. Is this typical?

Comment: What is the url of entry for the site? (homepage)

Comment: This is the front page to my site: http://isometricland.net/

Comment: The blog is in a sub-folder of the site.

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as accepted if it is correct and addresses your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Could be.

It is not necessary to have max traffic coming to the home page of the website.

In your situation, if you may be adding value to users from the blog then you have higher traffic on your blog.

The best way to analyse is by having Google Analytics installed on your static website as well as the blog and see whats happening.

Note: You also need to see if you may have spammer visiting your sites. And the good way to check is see if you may have spam entry to your blog post as comments.

Regardless, the best way to analyse is by having GA installed.

Comment: Yes, I have tons of spammers on the blog. Which is why I turned off comments for a long while. I have recently re-enabled comments.

Comment: I would encourage you to use GA and see users journey data. If you may add value to your user from your blog then instead of turning off, you may use some plugins (eg. Akismet Anti-Spam) which will filter out spam for you.

Comment: How do I tell if GA is capturing stuff from the blog?

Comment: You just need to have GA installed both on the website and the blog and then you can see the data and traffic by going to GA. GA >> Behavior >> Site Content >> All Pages

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll back up a couple of sections in the Webalizer report, you will see a section titled 'Top x of x Total URLs'. This is the most popular requested URLs, not necessarily pages but, if you see any of your pages there, those are the top.

In my Webalizer log, the third entry is for `/`, which is the site root so it is the most popular page because the two above it are resources loaded by the pages.

[image: Webalizer Top x of x Total URLs]

Webalizer reports are taken from the access logs directly on your web server so, it can be complicated. GA is a good tip to use in addition since it loads in page and directly logs the request and, will give you information about referrers etc.